# Proving that the subgroup of a given group is normal if it has unique index.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $|G:H|=n$ and no other subgroup of $G$ has index n in $G$. Prove that $H$ is normal.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that, for any $g \in G$, the map $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism.  Therefore, the restriction of $\phi$ to this subgroup $H$ is necessarily a group isomorphism.

Now that we know $H \cong \phi(H)$, what does this mean for $[G:H]$ and $[G: \phi(H)]$?  What can we conclude?

Comment: The above is true for *any automorphism* $\;\phi\;$ , not only for inner ones, making thus $\;H\;$ not merely normal but even cahracteristic in $\;G\;$ . +1

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any fixed $g\in G$, $H_{g}=\{ghg^{-1}|h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. And $|H_g|=|H|$ for all $g\in G$. Hence, $|G:H_{g}|=n$. However, no other subgroup has index $n$, thus $H_g=H$ for all $g\in G$. Then $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. So, $H$ is normal.

Comment: You need to be a little more careful here if the group is not finite, as then subgroups of the same order need not have the same index (the idea still works because the subgroups are assumed to be conjugate which is stronger).